How to calculate the probability of picking three numbers from a set of numbers with duplicates?
Suppose I have {4 6 6 8 9 10}
How would I calculate the probability of picking {4 6 6} from this? The order doesn't matter.
I'm currently in my third year of statistics but combinatorics is my absolute worst enemy. I was thinking something involving 6C2 * 5C1 * 4C1 but it isn't guaranteed that I pick 7 on my first try neither is it a probability.

What is the probability of picking a valid number in your first try? Assuming you picked a valid number, what is the probabilty of doing so in the second try? How about the third?

@jvdhooft Probability of first try valid is 3/6. Second try valid is 2/5 and third try is 1/4. In that case the answer to my question would be 3/6 multiplied by 2/5 multiplied by 1/4 which is 0.075?

The first part of your answer is correct, but you should arrive at $\frac{1}{20} = 0.05$.

It may help to think of your multiset as ${4, 6_1, 6_2, 8, 9, 10}$. I.e. temporarily assume that all the elements are unique, and then adjust for the non-uniqueness later (if necessary).

There are $\binom 63 = 20$ ways to choose a subset of $3$ elements from a set of $6$ elements.  In your problem, exactly one of those $20$ possible subsets is "good" and all $20$ subsets are equally likely, so the probability of choosing a "good" subset is $\frac{1}{20}=0.05$.
In your comment above, you've gotten the arithmetic wrong.  When you correct it, you'll have the right answer.
